# How to make a generic list equal another generic list

Tags: c#

This is my set up,

```
class CostPeriodDto : IPeriodCalculation
{
    public decimal? a { get; set; }
    public decimal? b { get; set; }
    public decimal? c { get; set; }
    public decimal? d { get; set; }
}

interface IPeriodCalculation
{
    decimal? a { get; set; }
    decimal? b { get; set; }
}

class myDto
{
    public List<CostPeriodDto> costPeriodList{ get; set; }

    public List<IPeriodCalculation> periodCalcList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.costPeriodList;  // compile error   
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 9):

Use `Cast<IPeriodCalculation>()` :

```
public class CostPeriodDto : IPeriodCalculation
{
    public decimal? a { get; set; }
    public decimal? b { get; set; }
    public decimal? c { get; set; }
    public decimal? d { get; set; }
}

public interface IPeriodCalculation
{
    decimal? a { get; set; }
    decimal? b { get; set; }
}

public class myDto
{
    public List<CostPeriodDto> costPeriodList { get; set; }

    public List<IPeriodCalculation> periodCalcList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.costPeriodList.Cast<IPeriodCalculation>().ToList();         
        }
    }
}
```

I believe in C#4, if you were using something implementing `IEnumerable<out T>`, you could simply do it the way you wrote it, and it would be resolved using [Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(VS.100).aspx).

```
class myDto 
{ 
    public IEnumerable<CostPeriodDto> costPeriodList{ get; set; } 

    public IEnumerable<IPeriodCalculation> periodCalcList 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return this.costPeriodList;  // wont give a compilation error    
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `return this.costPeriodList.Cast<IPeriodCalculation>().ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ methods to cast from one sequence to another will not be *equal*. That is to say that the following test would fail if you used `Cast()/ToList()`.

```
Assert.AreSame(myDto.costPeriodList, myDto.periodCalcList);
```

Furthermore, using those methods means that if you tried to add an item to one collection, they would not be reflected in the other. And every time you called periodCalcList, it would be creating an entirely new collection which could be disastrous depending on how many items, how frequently it's called, etc.

A better solution, in my opinion, is to not use `List<T>` for holding the CostPeriodDto and instead use a collection derived from `Collection<T>` and explicitly implement `IEnumerable<IPeriodCalculation>`. Optionally you could implement `IList<IPeriodCalculation>` if you needed to.

```
class CostPeriodDtoCollection :
    Collection<CostPeriodDto>, 
    IEnumerable<IPeriodCalculation>
{

    IEnumerable<IPeriodCalculation>.GetEnumerator() {
        foreach (IPeriodCalculation item in this) {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

}

class MyDto {
    public CostPeriodDtoCollection CostPeriods { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IPeriodCalculation> PeriodCalcList {
        get { return CostPeriods; }
    }
}
```